# Prove $g(x)=f^"(x)f(x)-2(f^{'}(x))^2<0$, where $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^m\binom{m}{i}x^{m-i}w_i$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convex-analysis

Consider $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^m\binom{m}{i}x^{m-i}w_i$, where $x\in[0,1]$ and $0\le w_{i+1}-w_i\le w_{i}-w_{i-1}$, $w_i>0$.

Determine the sign of $g(x)$, where $g(x)=f^"(x)f(x)-2(f^{'}(x))^2$, $f^",f^{'}$ is the second and first order derivative of $f$.

My result is: if $m=2$ and $m=3$, $g(x)<0$. So, I guess that $g(x)<0$ for $m=2,3,\cdots$. Do you have any idea to prove this? Thank you very much.

Comment: A remark; the derivative of $f'(x)/f(x)$ is $(f^"(x)f(x)-(f^{'}(x))^2)/f(x)^2$. Does it help ? I don't know ...