# Prove $a_0a_3-3a_1a_2\le 0$ hold when $0\le a_3-a_2\le a_2-a_1\le a_1-a_0$, and $0\le a_0\le a_1\le a_2 \le a_3$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

Suppose that $0\le a_3-a_2\le a_2-a_1\le a_1-a_0$, and $0\le a_0\le a_1\le a_2 \le a_3$. Then does this inequality $a_0a_3-3a_1a_2\le 0$ hold?

Comment: Looks connected to the question you asked half an hour ago (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2603193). In all cases, when questions are connected, you should mention it

Comment: yes, partial connected. but I really have no idea to how to connect other questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it holds.

Since we have $$0\le a_0\le 2a_1-a_2\quad\text{and}\quad 0\le a_3\le 2a_2-a_1$$
we have
$$\begin{align}a_0a_3-3a_1a_2&\le (2a_1-a_2)(2a_2-a_1)-3a_1a_2\\\\&=-2(a_1^2-a_1a_2+a_2^2)\\\\&=-2\left(\left(a_1-\frac{a_2}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}a_2^2\right)\le 0\end{align}$$